# Stop animation OnTriggerExit

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am using collider to play my animation onTriggerEnter and want to stop the animation onTriggerExit and play again onTriggerEnter and so on.

Here's the onTriggerEnter script:

```
var chestSound : AudioClip;
var treasureChest : GameObject; 
function OnTriggerEnter (col : Collider) {
    if(col.gameObject.tag == "Player") { 
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(chestSound, transform.position);
        treasureChest.animation.Play();
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: How about this example?
[link](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/712019/play-animation-ontriggerenter.html)

Comment: in this example onTriggerExit its play another animation i just want to stop the animation onTriggerExit an play again onTriggerEnter.

Comment: what's exactly wrong? did you try using `treasureChest.animation.Stop();`?

Comment: can you please write the code for onTriggerExit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I would write

```
function OnTriggerExit (col : Collider) {
 if(col.gameObject.tag == "Player") 
     treasureChest.animation.Stop();
 }
```

but it seems that maybe your use of `Destroy(gameObject)` could affecting the game. you are destroying your own player object as he triggers the other object, how could he go through OnTriggerExit?

Comment: yes you are write i just remove this Destroy(gameObject) and its work thanks.